# How to use open source bugtracking (for customers)?

Tags: bug-tracking

At the moment support requests / bug reports made by customers are coming in by mail. It is getting harder to organize priorities and stay at the helm of all this. So I am looking for bugtracking(?) tools. Not all reports are bugs of course, sometimes it's just feature request or support requests.

So my question is: whicht open source bugtracker / support request handling tool do you recommend? I know Mantis which seems to be my front runner for a more elaborate evaluation, but I already worked with it (as a reporter / contributor) and found the GUI a little cumbersome. Another issue is that I thought about using the tool for multiple website projects of different customers.

Intuitively I would prefer to run only one instance of the tool for all projects to have a better overview of all critical issues (independently of the project). Of course customer A should not be able to see customer Bs request (but every customer can have multiple reporting accounts) Is Mantis able to handle that? Can you recommend any other alternatives?

P.S.: I heard about Jira, but I will try to find a free tool for my first try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to use email with Mantis, so that you can get incoming email (directly or by forwarding) to Mantis.

Then you can have a workflow in Mantis, f.ex. have an incoming project and customer projects, and you can send email with bcc Mantis and subject containing issue number (I use [1234] as a pattern).

I haven't used other issue trackers as much, but my experience with a customized Mantis is good regarding different kinds of issues and using with email.

Comment: Thx, this is nice way to use mantis with different projects and still have an overview. I´ll also try to manage that setup. What I do not like about Mantis ist the GUI.  It scares non-technical users to hell. The advantage is, that already know it. If I understood you correctly, users just keep sending emails in you scenario ?

Comment: Yes. They can see and relate to the issue number, but not the tracker itself. Then you forward (or bcc own answer) to Mantis to keep the issue history up-to-date.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're turned to Open source, I'd say install a project management platform like Launchpad, redmine... etc and then create a project for each of your clients (of course you can have multiple accounts for only one client). The bug tracker in these platforms can serve as a support request service.

I'd go for Launchpad because it also has the Q/A feature and blueprints, and is also nice looking and very very user-friendly. And also damn easy to install on a Ubuntu Server.

Kind regards